# How do I write report from 2 different dataset linked by ID?

Tags: sql-server-2008, reportbuilder3.0

I am building a report in report builder.  I have 2 dataset, they **can't be merged** because of their complexity.  What I would like to do is make a report where it use the ID from the first dataset to look up data in the 2nd dataset.  Is this possible?  The following are example, not exact code, but what I need:

First Dataset:

```
select itemID from Items
```

Second Dataset:

```
select itemID, saleAmount, salePrice from Sales
```

I would like to setup my report like this:

```
ItemID        | Sale Count                                                  | Sale Price 
--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------
Items.itemID  | sum(Sales.saleAmount) where items.itemID = Sales.itemID     | sum(Sales.salePrice ) where items.itemID = Sales.itemID
```

So the end result will be like this:

```
ItemID        | Sale Count                                                  | Sale Price 
--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------+------------
1             | 11223                                                       | $123123
2             | 4537                                                        | $8375
```

Is this possible?  Maybe with Conditional Lookup?

Comment: use the join between two table and rum aggrigate function to achive the this report.

Comment: I can't combine the 2 dataset in SQL, I have to do it Report Builder, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame you can't join the data when creating the datasets.

Failing that, I can think of a couple of other options:

**Use LookupSet and custom code**

This excellent answer [How to combine aggregates within a group with aggregates across groups within SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093443/how-to-combine-aggregates-within-a-group-with-aggregates-across-groups-within-ss) has a perfect example of how you might do this.

Basically, you add custom code in a function (e.g. `SumLookup`) that accepts the results of a LookupSet call and returns the aggregated value. You'd have expressions like the following in your report:

```
=Code.SumLookup(
    LookupSet(Fields!itemID.Value, Fields!itemID.Value, Fields!saleAmount.Value, "Sales")
)
```

I created a quick test and it works perfectly.

**Use subreports**

To do this you'd create table based on the **Items** dataset, then in the detail row you'd embed a subreport to display the **Sales** information.

The subreport would need an `itemID` parameter to filter the Sales appropriately, you would set the parent table to pass `=Fields!itemID.Value` to the subreport - this would then repeat for each `itemID` row and display the relevant Sales data.

For what it's worth, I'd look at the first option - there is some custom code, but it's straightforward, and that way you wouldn't need to deploy multiple reports. Just seems cleaner to me.

Comment: Excellent!  I will try both and report back!

Comment: Worked well, I went with the subreport route because my queries were complex so I broke it up into smaller pieces.