# Sum all fields from lookup SSRS

Tags: sql, service, reporting-services, reporting, reportbuilder3.0

I try to sum in the end of a table, one column is a lookup. When i run it over multiple days and try to sum the lookup for all days like

```
=Sum(Lookup(Fields!.Value,Fields!.Value,Fields!.Value, "table_1")
```

If I keep it without the Sum, it only takes the first value from the first day. If I have the sum, a ridiculous number appears

Comment: Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8094130/3198474

Comment: @NaveenKumar i try to but the "SumLookup" gets red, any solution?

Comment: Have you added the SumLookup Function to your Custom Code in your Report Properties?

Comment: @user2900970 Yes i have, still not working. This image describes what i wanna do. I want to sum that lookup, expresseion of capacity. http://cdn.imghack.se/images/9af92a3e97839bf4238f9cb82b556c89.jpg