# SSRS How to get the first and last values of a matrix row group?

Tags: matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I basically have the screenshot below as my layout.

My matrix columns are DCG1 and DCG2.

At the end of the Matrix I have a Total Group, which works just find.  But I want to find the difference between my first and last value of the group.  I've tried everything from ReportItems! to values.  I cannot get SSRS to recognize these values.

So basically in the screen shots below.  Screen shot 1 is the matrix structure.  I have a column group called Test1, I want the first Value of Test1 and the last Value of Test 1 and place that in the Red box.

In screenshot 2, you can see the values i want to compare.  The table groupings are named the same as the column + group.  So dcs1group/dcs2group

[image]

[image]

Okay here is the DDL and DML for the datasource

`http://pastebin.com/1ySN701D`

The pastebin has been removed.  Why, not sure so here it is below.

```
IF EXISTS
      (SELECT [name]
         FROM tempdb.sys.tables
        WHERE [name] LIKE '%tmpHoldingTable%')
   BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #tmpHoldingTable;
   END;


CREATE TABLE #tmpHoldingTable
(
   dcs1    NVARCHAR (50),
   dcs2    NVARCHAR (50),
   Total   DECIMAL (10, 2),
   Test1   NVARCHAR (50)
)

INSERT INTO #tmpHoldingTable (dcs1,
                              dcs2,
                              Total,
                              Test1)
VALUES ('Contract',
        'Breach of Contract',
        500.00,
        '01/01/2013-12/31/2013'),
       ('Contract',
        'Breach of Contract',
        300.00,
        '01/01/2014-12/31/2014'),
       ('Employment',
        'Discrimination',
        500.00,
        '01/01/2013-12/31/2013'),
       ('Employment',
        'Discrimination',
        300.00,
        '01/01/2014-12/31/2014'),
       ('Employment',
        'Research',
        500.00,
        '01/01/2013-12/31/2013'),
       ('Employment',
        'Research',
        300.00,
        '01/01/2014-12/31/2014')

SELECT * FROM #tmpHoldingTable;
```

Comment: Did you tried using the `First(Fields!yourfield.value,"yourgroup")` and `Last(Fields!yourfield.value,"yourgroup")`

Comment: @CoderofCode  sure did!  but how do you use multiple groups?  Because what really matter is having all 3 groups!  dcs1/dcs2/test1.   ReportItems! doesn't work in this cause

Comment: @CoderofCode you get in this case -  has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggrgate function.

Comment: It would be good if you help us reproduce your scenario. Add some basic DDL and DML to set up sample tables that include problematic cases. In addition, some info on what the dataset and groupings for your tablixes would also help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but as you can see it is a bit complicated.

To make this a more generic answer, I have created my own **DataSet**, with simplified columns but more data:

```
select grp = 1, val = 100, dt = cast('01-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 1, val = 110, dt = cast('01-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 1, val = 200, dt = cast('02-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 1, val = 210, dt = cast('02-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 1, val = 300, dt = cast('03-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 1, val = 310, dt = cast('03-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 1, val = 400, dt = cast('04-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 1, val = 410, dt = cast('04-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 1, val = 500, dt = cast('05-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 1, val = 510, dt = cast('05-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 2, val = 220, dt = cast('02-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 2, val = 230, dt = cast('02-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 2, val = 320, dt = cast('03-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 2, val = 330, dt = cast('03-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 2, val = 420, dt = cast('04-jan-2015' as date)
union all select grp = 2, val = 430, dt = cast('04-jan-2015' as date)
```

[image]

Note that each *grp* / *dt* combination has two values, and that `grp 1` is over a longer range for *dt* than `grp 2`.

I have created a simple Matrix based on this:

[image]

Since you are using SQL Server 2012, you can use the `LookupSet` function to get the First/Last values per row group.

The expression in the **First** row group TextBox is:

```
=Code.SumLookup(
    LookupSet(
        First(Fields!dt.Value, "grp").ToString & Fields!grp.Value.ToString
        , Fields!dt.Value.ToString & Fields!grp.Value.ToString
        , Fields!val.Value
        , "DataSet1"
    )
)
```

Based on my sample data, this is giving my required results:

[image]

Note that the second `grp` row has a narrower range than the first, but its first/last columns are independent for each group so are correct within each `grp`.
There are quite a few things going on here.

**Custom code for aggregation of `LookUpSet` result**

The `LookupSet` expression is wrapped in a `Code.SumLookup` custom function:

```
Function SumLookup(ByVal items As Object()) As Decimal
  If items Is Nothing Then
    Return Nothing
  End If

  Dim suma As Decimal = New Decimal()
  suma = 0

  For Each item As Object In items
    suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
  Next

  Return suma
End Function
```

This is taken from the answer at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093443/how-to-combine-aggregates-within-a-group-with-aggregates-across-groups-within-ss) SO question.

This assumes that each matrix cell can be the sum of multiple values, so this needs to be summed up. `LookupSet` returns an array of values, which is aggregated by `Code.SumLookup`.

**Details for `LookupSet`**

Next, the `LoopupSet` expression itself:

```
    LookupSet(
        First(Fields!dt.Value, "grp").ToString & Fields!grp.Value.ToString
        , Fields!dt.Value.ToString & Fields!grp.Value.ToString
        , Fields!val.Value
        , "DataSet1"
    )
```

`LookupSet` takes the following parameters:

```
LookupSet(source_expression, destination_expression, result_expression, dataset)
```

In our expression, we want get all values from `DataSet1` that match the first `dt` in the current `grp` scope.

For `source_expression` I use:

```
First(Fields!dt.Value, "grp").ToString & Fields!grp.Value.ToString
```

This gets the first *dt* in the row scope (`"grp"` is the name of the row group), then appends this to the current *grp*. This creates an expression to match to a similar expression when seeking in `DataSet1`.

i.e. `destination_expression`:

```
Fields!dt.Value.ToString & Fields!grp.Value.ToString
```

Finally, we specify we want `Fields!val.Value` as the `result_expression` and `DataSet1` as the `dataset` parameter.

All matching `Fields!val.Value` values in `DataSet1` are constructed into an array by `LookupSet`, then aggregated by `Code.SumLookup`.

**Update expression for Last values**

The expression for the **Last** TextBox is practically the same; just change `First` to `Last`:

```
=Code.SumLookup(
    LookupSet(
        Last(Fields!dt.Value, "grp").ToString & Fields!grp.Value.ToString
        , Fields!dt.Value.ToString & Fields!grp.Value.ToString
        , Fields!val.Value
        , "DataSet1"
    )
)
```

**Get the Difference**

Finally, to get the difference of these, simply subtract one expression from the other in the **Difference** TextBox, or even reference the `ReportItems` values:

```
=ReportItems!Last.Value - ReportItems!First.Value
```

Where `Last` and `First` are the names of the TextBoxes.

**Conclusion**

Obviously you will need to update for your specific case, but you can see that this can be done.

Is it worth doing this in your report? You can see there are many steps involved, and in general would be easier to address when generating the DataSet. But, if that is not an option hopefully this `LookupSet` approach is useful.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible in SSRS alone. Believe me I've tried. Fortunately you have a SQL datasource so I would resolve this requirement there where you have (almost) unlimited powers to shape and manipulate data.

For example I would replace your final select with:

`; WITH CTE_Base AS (
SELECT * FROM #tmpHoldingTable
)
, CTE_Test1 AS (
SELECT Test1
    , ROW_NUMBER () OVER ( ORDER BY Test1 ) AS Column_Number_Test1
FROM CTE_Base
GROUP BY Test1
)
SELECT CTE_Base.*
    , CTE_Test1.Column_Number_Test1
    , CASE WHEN CTE_Test1.Column_Number_Test1 = 1 
            THEN Total
        WHEN CTE_Test1.Column_Number_Test1 = 
            ( SELECT MAX ( Column_Number_Test1 ) FROM CTE_Test1 ) 
            THEN 0 - Total
        ELSE 0
        END AS [Difference]
FROM CTE_Base
    INNER JOIN CTE_Test1
        ON CTE_Base.Test1 = CTE_Test1.Test1`

This adds a [Difference] column with a copy of [Total] for the 1st column and 0 - [Total] for the last column.

The SQL could probably be made more efficient, but hopefully breaking it into CTEs is easier to follow.

Then in the SSRS Designer you can add a [Difference] column outside the [Test1] column group and let it sum (default).

BTW your test data seems a bit simplistic - it will only produce 2 columns and all cells have values.  But its great you posted DDL & DML - it made it easy to extend the data and code and test this.

Comment: Mike - well it's my hope that it can be handled via SSRS.  Only two columns are irrelevant is you're always concerned with the first and last.   I was hoping maybe some kind of spiffy inScope function would work.  As you noted the dataset is simplistic.  I usually make everything as simple as I can and scale it out.  I'm sure there is a specific way to handle it via sql, however the real dataset and environment is much more complex

Comment: I too can recall that hope I felt when the Aggregate / Scope type functions were added to SSRS back in 2005.  Since then I have tried many times to stretch the boundaries of what they can do - the unfortunate reality is that they are very limited.