# SSRS chart, put single label for Median/Average, sharing my observation

Tags: ssrs-2012

it all started when I tried to put single label(value) for Median (that bloody 71.90). In my report I have only chart, no need anything else,  and it's interesting that if I hide tablix where I have Code.AddValue needed for Code.GetMedian()  nothing working, looks lik HIDE treated same like "Don't do anything" this is quite strange....
Another interesting thing that sequence is important also, If I moved tablix after chart -> goodbye my Median, nothing is displayed. I also put those textboxes with correspondig reference to display Median value.
I used Median Report function from [stackexchange(c)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/61185/find-the-median-of-a-calculated-field-in-ssrs-2012)

If anybody can help me how to solve this problem, I need only chart with median value, I don't want to use data points as I have too many categories, so it will be swamped. I also learned that you can put any textboxes inside chart.

you can take sample rdl from here[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hdnxjv8el9r59ix/Chart.rdl?dl=0)
Thanks all
Mario[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your **Code.GetMedian** relies on the table being created to populate the values it needs for the calculation (Function **AddValue**). When the table is hidden, the table isn't generated and the **AddValue** code isn't executed to add the values.

You can rework your report to use **LookUpSet** to get the values in one shot rather than using the table.

Here's a function to sum up the lookup set - you'd just need to change the SUM formula (below) to the median formula.

```
suma += Convert.ToDecimal(item)
```

[How to combine aggregates within a group with aggregates across groups within SSRS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8093443/how-to-combine-aggregates-within-a-group-with-aggregates-across-groups-within-ss)